# Full width hero unit in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In [this example layout](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html) I want only hero unit to be 100% wide and rest within the default grid. For example, [check this site](http://www.htc.com/in/). It has only the hero unit part (showcase area) in full width and rest in fixed width (navigation, bottom content, footer).

I need to do this without losing responsive design feature.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

move your `.hero-unit` div outside of your `.container` div.

the `.container` style confines you to a set width. and anything inside it will have a maximum width of it's parent.
instead of:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="hero-unit">
   </div>
</div>
```

use:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Well the answer is right but whenever you resize the site, hero-unit will then change to have spaces around (20px right, 20px left) because all the elements are bound to this `body has paddings in @media max-width: 767px`. Just do the code below to fix it too:

> @media (max-width: 767px) {
>     .hero-container {
>         margin-right: -20px;
>         margin-left: -20px;
>     }
>   }