# How can I break the grid? is there a common practice for this?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I am using bootstrap's grid, and I would like to have a div that "breaks" the grid and is streched to the borders of the screen ('width:100%').

my code looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
   div that is the width of the grid
  </div>
  <div class="unknown">
   div that breaks the grid and has full width
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

how can I achieve this? is it common practice to open many different containers, or can I do this with divs nested with the container?

Comment: This looks like the same problem possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482850/full-width-hero-unit-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: can you show your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use several containers rather than overriding the layout with custom styling.
Bootstrap themselves have examples with multiple containers being used, such as:
[the carousel](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html)